# QAction icon size

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

How can I modify QAction icon size in PyQt4?

I tried doing this:

Custom class:

```
class MyStyle(QCommonStyle):
    def pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, QStyleOption_option=None, QWidget_widget=None):
        if QStyle_PixelMetric == QStyle.PM_SmallIconSize:
            return 30
        return QCommonStyle.pixelMetric(self, QStyle_PixelMetric, QStyleOption_option, QWidget_widget)
```

rest of the code:

```
        self.popMenu = QMenu(parent)
        self.popMenu.setStyle(MyStyle())
```

Comment: You really need [QProxyStyle](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qproxystyle.html) for this, but it's only available in pyqt5, not pyqt4. Then again, on some platforms (e.g. mac), even this won't work, because the os handles the menus, so the qt style is ignored. Does your `pixelMetric` method ever get called? Try putting a `print` statement in there to see what is happening.

Comment: @ekhumoro yes, it get called. it usually returns (int, None, QMenu object)

Comment: After some experimentation with `QProxyStyle`, I found that it *does* create larger menu-items, but it *doesn't* automatically resize the icons as well (so you would need to supply icons with the correct size). On the other hand, `QCommonStyle` is no use at all, because it cannot render the menu-items properly - a fully implemented style class is needed for that (or `QProxyStyle`). However, pyqt4 does not provide any of those classes - so you must use pyqt5 to do what you want.